# Java EE deployment in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, intellij-idea

I have a fairly complex Java EE project which can be built fine from Maven. After importing it to IDEA, I had set up a working deployment of the frontend WAR and the backend EAR to a local Weblogic 12c server. The project also have several 'common' artifacts packaged as jars and used by both the frontend and backend artifacts. For deployment, I used the exploded artifacts to save some time on packaging/unpacking, everything works fine till that point.

During development, I edit some Java sources and try to redeploy the updated artifacts to the running Weblogic. I press Shift+F10, choose Redeploy artifacts, I see IDEA building the project, the project redeploys on the server, and more often than not, I do not see any of the recent changes. Even if I choose Rebuild project explicitly and then try to redeploy artifacts after, no changes can be seen on the server. The only safe way to make my changes appear in the deployed artifacts is to invoke maven from the command line calling the `package` goal, and then redeploying from IDEA. (No JRebel is installed, is being used either in the IDE or on Weblogic, and I'd like to stay that way).

Is that expected behaviour from IDEA? Could this be something specific to our project or something global? Should IDEA be able to discover which projects needs rebuilt and repackaged and then redeploy the EAR/WAR artifacts properly to the server? Does it need any help from my side achieving that goal?

Comment: Are the parts that you're changing marked as SNAPSHOT versions?  How does your ear/war have access to these libraries?  Does it use the module tag or just depend on it like a normal dependency?  I need these details to be able to answer.

Comment: Both the root project and the subprojects are using SNAPSHOT versions. All dependencies in the WAR and EAR modules are included as normal dependencies, no EJB module dependencies are used.

Answer (score 1):

Whats your run/debug configurations? Check this, if not already sois not.

in the quick menu, edit configurations > Run/debug configurations window:

- Server tab:

  - On 'update' action: restart server
  - Before launch: set 'run maven clean' and 'run maven install'
- Deplowment tab

  - inserts your ear's here.

Comment: I'm afraid you miss the point with my question. The goal is to 1) update the deployments without restarting the server, 2) achieve this completely within IDEA and without invoking maven explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

don't sure this specific answer your question but what I can suggest you is to try configure 
weblogic maven plugin

then you can execute deployment from command line / or from IDEA with maven support.

1. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hagaMr6UL6U

Comment: I'm afraid my comment to the other answer stands - "The goal is to ... achieve this completely within IDEA and without invoking maven explicitly."

Answer (score 0):

Evenif your final goal is to do the whole built process done by IntelliJ build and deployment options I will first try the following:
If your project was set up properly in maven you should be able to load you maven pom.xml within you IntelliJ. All the maven build commands and deployment setting you were doing through mvn command line will show up in your IntelliJ's maven panel in a nice three structure.

If this works out then clearly one of the libraries that are built through your IntelliJ build are not being deployed properly into the right location. You need to narrow down which one of the jars, the ear, or the war has to be affected by a single change you make and then check whether the date of the file is updated in the location it is to be deployed or not.

To wrap up, my humble sugestion though is to use either maven or gradle intelliJ panels for your J2EE projects. As you do achieve the defined goal of having your project built completely through the IntelliJ idea. Also whatever plugin you add to your maven shows up in you idea's maven/gradle panel. It is a fairly straight forward approach and you achieve a powerfull and flexible deployment and build tools within IntelliJ like your wanted.

Comment: The problem appearently is not with handling external dependencies but rather dependencies of other subprojects. Suggesting to use maven is quite contrary to my expressed goal to be able to do all that from with my IDE. Of course I use maven for this project and use it extensively at my CI server etc, but that's a completely different story.